# 18.04 - Problem with setting up DHCP and static IP addresses on one interface?

Tags: dhcp

I have configured the netplan: (config below)

```
Network:
   version: 2
   renderer: NetworkManager
   ethernets:
     enp2s0:
       dhcp4: no
       dhcp6: no
       addresses:
        - 192.168.76.101/24
      enp1s0:
        dhcp4: yes
        dhcp6: no
        addresses:
          - 192.168.2.13/24
```

The problem is when the device restarts and the DHCP server is not available, the `enp1s0` shows error in connecting.

If I type `ip a`, the `enp1s0` does not show any IP address. It should show at least the static `192.168.2.13`, but it is not showing.

The remote PC cannot ping this IP neither.

It works well only if the DHCP IP is present. The remote PC can ping both IP addresses.

Is there a way to make static IP `192.168.2.13` as primary for `enp1s0`? So it will not matter if the DHCP is available or not. (I am not sure if making the static as primary will fix the issue).

Add comments:
Is there a way to fill the GUI of IPv4 address "192.168.2.13/24" in script, when the DHCP is not available?

Comment: As far as I am aware, you can have static *OR* DHCP but not both in fallback using netplan. Is there some reason you don't set enp1s0 as static and be done? You also need gateway4 and nameservers. Please see: `/usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/static.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: It's an automated machine communicating with static IP, the DHCP is used when it needs to get updates.